# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^k$. Let $m \geq \frac{1}{2}k$. Show that $G^{(m)} =\{ e \}$.

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question in group theory:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^k$. Let $m \geq \frac{1}{2}k$. Show that $G^{(m)} ={e}$, where $G^{(m)}$ is the m-th derived subgroup.

What I've done is to check the orders of each $G^{(i)}$. If  $|G^{(i)}| > p$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$, and if there exists an $1\leq i \leq k$ such that $|G^{(i)}| \leq p$.

I'm stuck with the latter case when $m<i$. I assume I need to disprove this case, as if $G^{(m)} = \{ e \}$ then it would be impossible.

I would love to get some help on this.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $|G/[G,G]| \ge p^2$ for all finite $p$-groups $G$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I've done in the former case. However, I did not understand how to apply this to the latter case. Do I need to calculate $[G:G^{(m)}]$ ?

Comment: As I said it follows immediately from that fact. Think about it!

Comment: Does this involve using:

 $$[G^{(m)} : G^{(i+1)}] = [G^{(m)} : G^{(i)}][G^{(i)} : G^{(i+1)}]  $$?

Comment: Yes, and you only need it with $m=1$.